# Where do I put app ID for admob with expo?

Tags: react-native, admob, expo

Where should I put `app ID` with admob for expo.  I know to put `ad unit ID` in like this and comment the correct one:

```
<AdMobBanner
            style={styles.bottomBanner}
            // adUnitID="ca-app-pub-..." //ios
            // adUnitID="ca-app-pub-..." //android />
```

My question is do I even need the app ID/ if so where would I put it?

Comment: Refer this link : https://blog.expo.io/adding-admob-to-your-expo-project-aa4e48ac848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the platform module if you want your app ID to be different from `Android` and `ios`.

```js
import { Platform } from "react-native";
...
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="fullBanner" // Choose what you want by size ex) largeBanner/mediumRectangle/..etc
  adUnitID={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ca-app-pub...ios" : "ca-app-pub...android"} // Test ID, Replace with your-admob-unit-id
  testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
  onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
```

`adAppID` is not required. Only `adUnitID` is required. And when testing is done with a physical device, you might need a `deviceID` for the `testDeviceID`.

Comment: That definitely helps cleanup my code for adUnitID, appreciate it.  The question I am asking is where do I put the  "ad App ID"

Comment: 'adAppID' is not required. Only 'adUnitID' is required. And when testing is done with a physical device, you might need a device ID for the 'testDeviceID'.

Comment: That's the answer I needed.  I wasn't sure if it was required as it looks that way in Admob documenation!  Please edit above to include with answer as I gave you the check!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter appId in the app.json file.. so it would look like below

```
{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "YOUR APP_ID HERE"
      },

      // --OTHERS RELATED TO ANDROID HERE--

    },

    // -- OTHERS RELATED TO EXPO HERE--

  }
}
```